# What are the brackets after a call to a Javascript function doing?

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, callback

So I found this script online, and I understand all except for 2 parts:

1) var first = getUrlVars()["id"];
    var second = getUrlVars()["page"];

I've never seen a function with brackets after it, what does it mean/do?

2) function(m,key,value)

Where are these parameters coming from (m, key, value)?

window.location would be: http://papermashup.com/index.php?id=123&page=home

```
function getUrlVars() {
var vars = {};
var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m,key,value) {
vars[key] = value;
});
return vars;
}

var first = getUrlVars()["id"];
var second = getUrlVars()["page"];

alert(first);
alert(second);
```

Comment: getUrlVars() returns an array or object, [..] denotes property access to the return value's array elements or properties.

Comment: 1) the function returns an object `{id:1,page:2}` and `getUrlVars()["id"]` returns 1 (in this example). 2) read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace especially "Specifying a function as a parameter". It is very interesting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`var first = getUrlVars()["id"];`

This line is calling the `getUrlVars()` function, and then accessing the `id` property of the return object and then setting the `first` variable to the value of that property.

`function(m,key,value)` is an anonymous function passed as a parameter to the `replace` function on the `String` object. [Docs here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). Essentially, it's passing a function into this parameter of the `replace` function:

> A function to be invoked to create the new substring (to put in place of the substring received from parameter #1). The arguments supplied to this function are described in the "Specifying a function as a parameter" section below.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1) It's basically just chaining, you take advantage of knowing that getUrlVars will return an object, the brackets reference a property on the returned object.

2)Pretty similar logic. window.location.href returns a String, you chain the .replace() method.

`function(m,key,value)` is the callback you pass to replace(), it's a standard JS method, you can see the docs (with the argument descriptions) here: [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

Answer (score 0):

The `()` are a **method invocation**.

The method returns a *dictionary* object (initialized as `var vars = {}`). With `vars["something"]` you do a *dictionary lookup* to retrieve data from the returned object.

You can rewrite ypur code to a *faster* version:

```
var dict = getUrlVars(); // Build dictionary (method invocation)
var first = dict["id"]; // Lookup
var second = dict["page"]; // Lookup
```

Shorter code is neither faster, nor more readable.